# I can't scroll applications after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, scrolling

I can't scroll down the applications which are shown after clicking the Show Applications button with my touchpad after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.

Comment: Which application? Are you using a mouse or a touchpad? Kindly [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1303870/edit) your question to add more information.

Comment: With my touchpad.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how but i can scroll down applications when i keep my dock at bottom instead of left or right. It may be temporary solution.